# Implementing a factory for the Composite pattern

Tags: .net, design-patterns, decorator, factory, composite

I have the following simulation data:

```
interface ISimulationData
{
    string Name { get; }
    int[] Heights { get; }
    int[] Temperatures { get; }
}
```

And the following interface for generation:

```
interface ISimulation
{
    void Generate();
}
```

Using the **Composite** pattern to represent single or multi-simulations:

```
interface ISimpleSimulation : ISimulation
{
    int Height { get; }
    int Temperature { get; }
}

interface IMultiSimulation : ISimulation
{
    IEnumerable<ISimulation> GetSimulations();
}
```

And I have the following **factory** interface:

```
interface ISimulationFactory
{
    ISimulation CreateSimulation(ISimulationData simulationData);
}
```

Concrete implementations for the simulation types:

```
class SimpleSimulation : ISimpleSimulation
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Temperature { get; set; }

    public SimpleSimulation(int height, int temperature)
    {
        Height = height;
        Temperature = temperature;
    }

    public void Generate()
    {
        //Height/temperature parameters used here.
    }
} 

abstract class MultiSimulation : IMultiSimulation
{
    public void Generate()
    {
        foreach (ISimulation subSimulation in GetSimulations())
        {
            subSimulation.Generate();
        }
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<ISimulation> GetSimulations();
}
```

If more than one height is specified, then a simulation is generated for each height:

```
class MultiHeightsSimulation : MultiSimulation
{
    private readonly int[] _heights;

    public MultiHeightsSimulation(int[] heights)
    {
        _heights = heights;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ISimulation> GetSimulations()
    {
        ISimulationFactory factory = new SimulationFactory();

        foreach (int height in _heights)
        {
            //yield return factory.CreateSimulation(???);
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, if more than one temperature is specified, then a simulation is generated for each temperature:

```
class MultiTemperaturesSimulation : MultiSimulation
{
    private readonly int[] _temperatures;

    public MultiTemperaturesSimulation(int[] temperatures)
    {
        _temperatures = temperatures;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ISimulation> GetSimulations()
    {
        ISimulationFactory factory = new SimulationFactory();

        foreach (int temperature in _temperatures)
        {
            //yield return factory.CreateSimulation(???)
        }
    }
}
```

Concrete implementation for the factory:

```
class SimulationFactory : ISimulationFactory
{
    public ISimulation CreateSimulation(ISimulationData simulationData)
    {
        if (simulationData.Heights.Length > 1)
        {
            return new MultiHeightsSimulation(simulationData.Heights);
        }

        if (simulationData.Temperatures.Length > 1)
        {
            return new MultiTemperaturesSimulation(simulationData.Temperatures);
        }

        return new SimpleSimulation(simulationData.Heights[0], simulationData.Temperatures[0]);
    }
}
```

Now I'm confused as to how to proceed with the following:

- Handling combined multi-height AND multi-temperature scenario?

I've only shown height and temperature, but there are many other parameters that behave the same way, so I'm really looking for a proper solution that handle those multi-X scenarios, with minimal coupling.

- `ISimulationFactory` has only one method exposed, which takes `ISimulationData`.

Now, you can see that `MultiHeightsSimulation` and `MultiTemperaturesSimulation` are calling the factory to create (simple) simulations at a specific height/temperature. Currently, there are no such methods provided by the factory and I was wondering if it makes sense to expose those methods in the factory? Wouldn't that confuse the clients of `ISimulationFactory` who are not supposed to be aware of the implementation details of the factory?

Looking forward to hear your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: The situation you're describing smells like a `Decorator` use case for me. I'll think better about it and get back to you.

Comment: I feel like there is a lot of over-engineering going on here...  Do you feel that all of the complexity is necessary?

Comment: does clients also want to create SimpleSimulations? if no, can you make SimpleSimulation factory overloads internal?

Answer (score 0):

Your simulation factory already accepts an `ISimulationData` parameter that has arrays for the two variables that you're currently concerned with:

```
int[] Heights { get; }
int[] Temperatures { get; }
```

One option would be to have `SimulationFactory` generate one simulation for each combination of the elements in these arrays (kind of a cartesian product). So if you had only one height and 5 temperatures, you'd implicitly have your `MultiTemperaturesSimulation`. However you could also pass in 5 heights and 4 temperatures, in which case the factory would generate 20 simulations (one for each combination of height and temperature)...

This would be fairly easy to adapt to handle more dimensions, as you add these, later. So you could have 3 humidities, 4 heights and 5 temperatures, which would result in 3 x 4 x 5 = 60 simulations.

You probably want to add some code to make sure that there is at least one element in each of the arrays in the `ISimulationData` parameter to the factory in this case (since if any of the arrays has zero elements then you end up with zero simulations - which likely doesn't make sense and should result in an `ArgumentException`).